# How can I find variable which greater than specific number in Linux?

Tags: linux, command

I have a one File, in this file I have over a thousand lines. I want find datas greater than specific data. For example:

I have the lines in file

```
Demo 11 demodemodemo
Demo 12 demodemodemodemo
Demo 14 demodemodemob
Demo 17 demodemodemobl
Demo 20 demodemodemobla
Demo 25 demodemodemoblab
Demo 89 demodemodemoblabla
Demo 67 demodemodemoblabl
```

I want find lines greater than 30 which located in 11,12,14,17,20,25,89,67. Is there anyone use this or have experience with this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean `lines greater than 30`? Can you be more specific?

Comment: greater than `30` I understand `which located in 11,12,14,17,20,25,89,67` I don't

Comment: Yes Allan, 
oguzismail  
Demo 17 demodemodemobl - is line
Demo 20 demodemodemobla -  is line
Demo 25 demodemodemoblab - is line

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
cat yourfile.txt | awk '{if($2>30)print $2}' #this will show your numbers greater than 30
```